# Can not run commands on my ROS directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my ros folder i have tried to do:

a@s:/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros$ git pull

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

a@s:/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros$ catkin_make

Base path: /opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros

The specified source space "/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros/src" does not exist

Does anyone knows why i got this errors?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204041/can-not-run-commands-on-my-ros-directory/) by [Luis_Neves_555](https://answers.ros.org/users/21744/luis_neves_555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Entering these commands does not make sense. You seem to be working with a system install of ROS. This should already work without doing anything to it. What are you trying to achieve?

Both commands are issued in a directory that is neither a repository nor a ROS package.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0